# Recursively resolve User Reference in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I don't quite understand what happens to my user reference when retrieving a data object in my ASP.NET app. Sketch of the code:

```cs
public class DataPoint
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }

    // data
}
```

Here's the code from the controller that creates these data entities:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(DataPoint dataPoint)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());   
    dataPoint.Owner = user;
    // ...
}
```

Now, when I inspect the database, the `DataPoint` records have an ID referencing the correct `ApplicationUser` ID. But when looking up a `DataPoint` like this:

```cs
DataPoint dataPoint = await db.DataPoints.FindAsync(id);
```

All data fields are populated as expected, except for the "Owner" field, which is `null`. Why is that? Do I have to trigger resolving this reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

1. `db.DataPoints.FindAsync(id);` does exactly that: find the `DataPoint` identitfied by `id`. You didn't ask for the `Owner` to be included. If you want that you should do:

   ```
   db.DataPoints.Include(d => d.Owner).Single(d => d.Id == id)
   ```

   This is called *eager loading*.
2. `Owner` can't be loaded on demand (i.e. by *lazy loading*) because for that to happen the property must be virtual:

   ```
   public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
   ```

   Now EF will create a dynamic proxy object for `DataPoint` that will load its `Owner` from the database as soon as it's accessed. (While the context is still alive, not disposed).

Answer (score 0):

You should define two properties for the same field to make the relation works. The property `public ApplicationUser Owner` it's called navigation property (you will use it to navigate to the referenced entity). What is missing in your model is the actual field containing the foreign key of your table.

You should edit your model like this:

```
public class DataPoint
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; } //read the note below


    public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }

    // data
}
```

NOTE:
Obviously everything works properly in the code above only if the field that contains the FK is an integer and it's name respects the entity framework naming convention for relationships :

```
ReferencedTableName   => name of the target table
Id                    => referenced table primary key name
ReferencedTableNameId => referencing field (in referencing table)
```

If the databse scheam does not complies with the naming convention you have to manually set the relationship with the `ModelBuilder` object or using data annotation attributes.